# C# Libgit2sharp : Failed to write chunk header: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, git, libgit2sharp

I am using to Libgit2Sharp to push , pull , merge .. etc some big text files to github through the application I am working on

when I try to push 8 xml files with size of 260 Megabyte , Libgit2Sharp raises " **Failed to write chunk header: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response** " exception .

In contrast , I could push the same files with the same size using Git bash .

Here is my code .

```
var pushOptions = new PushOptions
{
    CredentialsProvider = new CredentialsHandler((url, usernameFromUrl, types) =>
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials()
    {
        Username = username,
        Password = password,
    }),
    OnPushStatusError = errors =>
    {
        _dialogCoordinatorInstance.ShowMessageAsync(this, "GIT Push Failed", ExceptionMessages.GetGitExceptionMessage(errors.Message)).ConfigureAwait(true);
        pushSucceed = false;
    },

};
try
{
    await Task.Run(() => _repository.Network.Push(_repository.Head, pushOptions)).ConfigureAwait(true);
    pushSucceed = true;
}
```

The code works pretty fine with smaller total files' sizes .  I don't know if Libgit2Sharp has maximum size for pushing files or not , but if it has . what would you recommend ?